# Visual Studio Web Deploy Error at Start Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, msdeploy, visual-web-developer

I am working on Visual Studio 2015 Web API project.

I have created Web Empty Project with API Option click. I choose Web Deploy option in process to publish web api app on server. I have created custom profile, provide the require detail and successfully pass the 'Validate Connection' but get error at preview page of publish Web Wizard.

### error

```
Web deployment task failed. (The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.)

The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.
Default credentials cannot be supplied for the Basic authentication scheme.
Parameter name: authType
```

### My Web.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>
<appSettings></appSettings>
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
 <httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules>
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
    preCondition="managedHandler"/>
  </modules>
  </system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the AuthType to NTLM in your publish profile (.pubxml):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AuthType>NTLM</AuthType>
```